# Simple Back button?

Tags: 7, javascript

I was using window.history.back() ,

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Back</a>
```

and

```
<script>
function goBack(){
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

but it is not working in d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery we can

```
(function ($) {  
  // Go back
  $('a.back').click(function(){
     parent.history.back();
     return false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

and add class="back" to your link

```
<a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rely on javascript, you could use `referer_uri()` in Drupal 6. I'm not sure about the Drupal 7 equivalent but I'll update this when I find it.

**Edit:** It would seem as referer_uri only returns `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` anyways which isn't really that reliable. It could however be used with the javascript version as a fallback plan. That way, you'll get some of those with javascript disabled.